# Error creating model version using "gcloud ml-engine versions create"

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

When I create a version of a machine learning model (whether it is my own model or the ML Engine [census example](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction)) using the command:

> gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 \
>   --model $MODEL_NAME \
>   --origin $MODEL_BINARIES \
>   --runtime-version 1.4

I get an error saying:
***ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) Failed accessing the model. Please make sure that the Cloud ML Api was enabled recently and retry. If that doesn't resolve this issue, please contact Cloud ML.***

Things I tried:

1. Different versions of --runtime-version
2. Re-enabled ML Engine API, created models again, created successful jobs multiple times.
3. To confirm that it is not an error with my own model, I again implemented the ML engine census [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction) from scratch. This [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction) had worked perfectly for me when I had tried in Feb 2018.

I still get the same error even for the tutorial.

Any pointers on how to fix this?

Has anyone tried to create model version as shown in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction) since April 19, 2018?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It is recommended to run {gcloud components update} to install the latest GCloud, then follow the instructions. Use gcloud ml-engine versions create `{MODEL_VERSION} --model={MODEL_NAME} --origin={MODEL_PATH(PICKLED FILE)} --runtime-version="1.6" --framework="e.g SCIKIT_LEARN" `

Comment: Abdul, yes I ran the gcloud components update. I also installed tensorflow 1.6 and ran 'gcloud ml-engine versions create' with the parameters. I still get the same error. Just to make sure that it is not an error with my own model,  I implemented the ML engine census tutorial[1] from scratch. I still get the same error. In fact the same tutorial worked perfectly for me in Feb 2018. Just curious, did you try this tutorial[1] in past week or so? Are you able to get the model version created successfully?  [1]https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction

Comment: Are you creating model version with Runtime-version=1.6?

Comment: Yes. I also tried several runtime versions starting from 1.4. I also installed the corresponding version of TensorFlow in GCP.

Answer (score 1):

After running this code:

```
gsutil ls -r $OUTPUT_PATH/export
```

It will generate a new timestamp in the path link
**Use that timestamp**

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

```
gsutil ls -r $OUTPUT_PATH/export
```

In the output, you can see a number (like 1569256565). It's the new timestamp

Run this command with the new timestamp :

```
MODEL_BINARIES=$OUTPUT_PATH/export/census/<timestamp>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that modelbinaries is the full path folder that contains the checkpoints. Typically, this will be gs://.../.../.../timestamp, i.e. end with a timestamp

Comment: Hi Lak, yes MODEL_BINARIES is the whole path that contains gs://$BUCKET_NAME/../export/../timestamp. I get the same error. I even tried installing tensorflow corresponding versions for different versions of the --runtime-version.  I am wondering what is causing this error.